# How can I keep a grid item that is set as resizable from going outside the div

Tags: html, css

Don't know if I am being dumb but I am trying to have a 2x2 grid of resizable items. I can get them all working but upon trying to set a max width for the item so it does not go off the screen it works but if you keep dragging it it ignores the max size of the grid. It holds at the max size I set for a few seconds but if I don't release the mouse it eventually goes outside the max size.
My CSS is as follows and the item in question is item 2.

```css
.grid-container {
  margin: 0px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(90%) fit-content(90%) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(8ch) fit-content(8ch) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #439cea;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 99%;

}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;

}

.item1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 2;
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.item2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
  max-height: fit-content;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-width: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 1 / span 2;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / span 1 / span 2;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would get better answers if you included a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ethan can you upload HTML and CSS both in the question or in Code Snippet. Then it's easier to resolve your issue.

Comment: @asyncawait Updated it with basic html example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not restrict the resizing of `.resizable` element, but only the parent, just using `overflow: hidden;` and `max-width` on the parent will prevent it from appearing to grow beyond restrictions. If you want to restrict the children from growing, the way I did this was to use css variable and calc on the root to determine the size of children. I also used box-sizing to account for the scroll bar height / width;

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --container-max-width: 200px;
  --resizable-max-width: calc(var(--container-max-width) / 2);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

  max-width: var(--container-max-width);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.resizable {
  max-width: var(--resizable-max-width);
  border: 1px solid black;

  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="resizable"></div>
  <div class="resizable"></div>
  <div class="resizable"></div>
  <div class="resizable"></div>
</div>
```